# Windows Phone 8.1: How to use Application Insights in BackgroundTask?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, azure-application-insights

I've followed the advice from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852654/can-i-use-app-insights-in-a-background-agent) and added the Application Insights Core package to BackgroudTask in Windows Phone 8.1 project. In Run method I initialized the TelemetryClient and provided my InstrumentationKey. Everything was working fine debugging on emulator and on my phone. After I published my app to the store no one was able to download it, because they were getting error code 80073cf9.

Can anyone from Application Insight makes help us with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what is the root cause for this issue but there are other threads (For example, search for  80073cf9 in here   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c3dec5f2-0434-4747-b044-07f14c771fe1/ai-crashing-my-app-upon-restart?forum=ApplicationInsights), that complains on the same issue.

Given our initial investigation this issue is not related to App Insights. The developer from the attached thread re-upload his app to the store, with App Insights, and it worked.

You might want to try Mark W's answer regarding error 80073cf9:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdapps/80073cf9/da1829dc-7f5e-4a5e-8cdf-ab64e68d6d60?auth=1

Thanks,
Izik